# What does a mni split AC do for thermostat?

Tags: air-conditioning, mini-split

I have a Hessaire mini split in a garage room.  It's installed in the wall and has a remote.  It acts like it has thermostat control (you can set the temp), but it is all over the place temperature wise. I don't mean that it seems random or definitely broken, but you have to adjust it significantly based on the outside temp. Does it try to get the temperature from the unit itself somehow? Is it an option to get some sort of remote temp sensor?

Comment: What model? The one online owners manual I just looked at had described a remote control, but didn’t mention thermostatic control.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the Mitsubishi's I have measure the temperature of the intake air at the unit. They specifically mention that they do not measure temperature at the remote. That's probably common.

They are stable as set in my experience.

That may be influenced by the fact that the building is well insulated, and they have a fan vane system that does a good job mixing the air. If your room is poorly insulated and/or the fan fails to mix the air well, it would be possible to get into cases where the temperature at the unit is wildly different from the temperature elsewhere in the room. An auxiliary fan might help with that. If the unit has the option of setting the fan vanes to move, try using that option, if you are not currently doing so.